# como usar JFileChooser en un servlet y llamar este servlet desde un jsp para que permita seleccionar la ubicacion donde se quiere guardar el archivo

Tags: jsp, servlets, apache-poi

Tengo este main que funciona correctamente:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String dirFolder = "" + chooser.getSelectedFile() + "";
            FunctionsOfZip zipFun = new FunctionsOfZip();
            zipFun.InputReader(dirFolder);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }
    }
```

Lo que sucede es que si quiero hacer este mismo código dentro de un `servlet` no se me ejecuta, soy nuevo en esto, estuve buscando información, lo que realmente quiero hacer es que desde un `jsp` con un enlace  llame al `servlet` y  me deje seleccionar la ubicación donde quiero guardar el archivo, hay ejemplo que utilizan en el `jsp: input type="file"` dentro del `form`
para subir archivo, pero lo que necesito es bajar el archivo y darle una ubicación , perdón si me he explicado de mal manera, espero sus consejos y buenas vibras :) ayudaaaa

Comment: JFileChooser no va a funcionar en un servlet. Lo suyo es que uses `jsp`, como dices, para subir archivos. Si lo que quieres es que se descargue un fichero, simplemente con tener un enlace al fichero sería suficiente. Si el fichero no está expuesto directamente, tendrías que poner un enlace a una función del servlet que devolviera ese fichero

Comment: hola javi, muchas gracias por responder, alguna pagina o ejemplo, entendí un poco la idea solo que el fichero input type= file solo da la opción de abrir archivo , yo lo que intento es guardar un excel que creer en un servlet, pero lo quiero guardar en una carpeta seleccionada por el usuario, hasta el momento logro guardarlo y queda en la carpeta predeterminada de descarga necesito corregir esto a que se habra un explorador de archivo que permita guarda el archivo